# pip install (kivy ) Error in visuale code and pycharm

Tags: python, kivy

I can't `install kivy`

```
python -m pip install kivy
```

the error is:

```
PS C:\\Users\\med\\source\\repos\\PythonApplication2\> python -m pip install kivy Collecting kivy

Using cached Kivy-2.2.1.tar.gz (24.0 MB)

Installing build dependencies ... error

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully. exit code: 1

\[12 lines of output\]

Collecting setuptools

Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB) Collecting wheel

Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.wh1.metadata (2.2 kB) Collecting packaging

Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.wh1.metadata (3.2 kB)

Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,\<=0.29.33,\>=0.24

Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)

Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev\~=0.3.3

Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.wh1.metadata (215 bytes)

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev=0.6.0 (from versions: 0.7.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev\~=0.6.0

\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error

x pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.

exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. PS C:\\Users\\med\\source\\repos\\PythonApplication2\> ^C
```

I try to `install kivy`

I can't install it.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Kivy only supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.11.

Comment: version of Python : Python 3.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Kivy does not support python version 3.12 yet.